# cortex-m3 fpu instruction hard fault

Tags: stm32, cortex-m

My firmware for stm32f103 results in hard fault.
Here is the line of code that crash execution:

```
 float shuntResistance = p[SHUNT_RESISTANCE];
```

where p - is global array of floats:

```
float p[CONFIG_NUM_PARAMS];
```

There is dissaembly while debugging:

```
0800177c:   ldr r3, [pc, #332]      ; (0x80018cc <adcSetConstants+336>)
0800177e:   vldr s10, [r3, #48]     ; 0x30 ; on that instruction program results in hard fault
```

Here is compiler flags:

```
-c -fmessage-length=0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mfloat-abi=softfp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fsingle-precision-constant
```

Linker flags:

```
-Wl,--static,--gc-sections,-Map=${ProjName}.map,-T../stm32_flash.ld -fmessage-length=0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fsingle-precision-constant -Dprintf=iprintf -u _printf_float -lc -lnosys -lc
```

Used compiler is launchpad's arm-none-eabi-gcc.
Used IDE is eclipse.
What is the cause?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your registers after the hardfault?

Comment: Also, take a look here: https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3a%2f%2fmy.st.com%2fpublic%2fSTe2ecommunities%2fmcu%2fLists%2fcortex_mx_stm32%2fF2%20floating%20point%20call%20causes%20hard%20fault&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=398

Comment: My understanding is that the cortex-m3 does not have an fpu.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M

Comment: @dwelch: that is correct but you can still use soft fpu library with cortex M3.

Comment: vldr is with an fpu register is not a soft float thing it is hard float yes?

Comment: can you reduce the code to just something that breaks?  what other command line options have you used?  reduce the command line options to something that still breaks or works and then evaluate what you really need or of two conflict

Comment: Yes, but why compiler use hard float instructions?

Comment: Clearly, 'softfp' links to library that use hard float instructions. There is must to be: '-mfloat-abi=soft'

Comment: Dwelch, maybe you will add your comment as an answer, and I will mark the topic as solved?

Comment: Yep, I think @dwelch hit the nail on the head.  I saw the compiler switches and assumed it was ok but yeah, the VLDR instruction is for hard float.  see: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15451.html

Answer (score 2):

> Here is compiler flags:
>
> `-c -fmessage-length=0 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mfloat-abi=softfp`

Your MCU is a Cortex M3, which has no FPU. You need to use `-mfloat-abi=soft`. The "softfp" option uses FPU instructions which will not work for you.